# How to correctly calculate the length of the text, taking into account hyphens and tabs js?

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of text, which is perceived by notepad and the back end as 1026 characters long text (because it has a hyphen in it). But the javascript length property defines it as text 1024 characters long, which allows client validation to pass, how can this be fixed?

**Example of the text:**

```
London is the capital and largest city of England and the United Kingdom, with a population of just under 9 million.[1] It stands on the River Thames in south-east England at the head of a 50-mile (80 km) estuary down to the North Sea, and has been a major settlement for two millennia.[9] The City of London, its ancient core and financial centre, was founded by the Romans as Londinium and retains its medieval boundaries.[note 1][10] The City of Westminster, to the west of the City of London, has for centuries hosted the national government and parliament. Since the 19th century,[11] the name "London" has also referred to the metropolis around this core, historically split between the counties of Middlesex, Essex, Surrey, Kent, and Hertfordshire,[12] which since 1965 has largely comprised Greater London,[13] which is governed by 33 local authorities and the Greater London Authority.[note 2][14]
```

As one of the world's major global cities,[15] London exerts a strong influence on its arts, entertainment, fashion,

**Example saved in js variable:**

```
  const text =
  'London is the capital and largest city of England and the United Kingdom, with a population of just under 9 million.[1] It stands on the River Thames in south-east England at the head of a 50-mile (80 km) estuary down to the North Sea, and has been a major settlement for two millennia.[9] The City of London, its ancient core and financial centre, was founded by the Romans as Londinium and retains its medieval boundaries.[note 1][10] The City of Westminster, to the west of the City of London, has for centuries hosted the national government and parliament. Since the 19th century,[11] the name "London" has also referred to the metropolis around this core, historically split between the counties of Middlesex, Essex, Surrey, Kent, and Hertfordshire,[12] which since 1965 has largely comprised Greater London,[13] which is governed by 33 local authorities and the Greater London Authority.[note 2][14]\n' +
  '\n' +
  "As one of the world's major global cities,[15] London exerts a strong influence on its arts, entertainment, fashion,"


console.log(String(text).length)
```

Comment: The formatting makes it a bit hard to read, your first example seems to have two \n return characters? If I make the return characters the same, I get the same letter count in a text editor and in javascript.

Comment: The issue does not lay in the hyphens, at least not directly. What database are you using? What text encoding is the database using? When I type `"-".length` it returns 1 character, because it is one character long. I assume the issue is probably with the way database stores the data, however you have not given as any information on that